# Accessing Headers when extending ng.resource.IResourceClass

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngresource

If I extend the `IResourceClass` like so:

```
interface UserResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<UserResource> {}
```

Then when I try to access the headers when I `query`:

```
userResource.query({})
    .$promise
    .then(
        (data, headers) => {
            vm.headers = JSON.parse(headers("X-Pagination"))
            vm.users = data;
        }
    )
```

it will give a compile error because the type definitions don't provide for the additional `headers` parameter. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Promises don't have an additional header parameter.

Comment: @georgeawg any suggestions? Is there a different interface I should use and avoid the `.$promise` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `headers` function is exposed as the second argument of the optional success callback:

```
vm.users = userResource.query({}, successCB)

function successCB (data, headers) {
    vm.headers = JSON.parse(headers("X-Pagination"))
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $resource Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#$resource-returns)